# Find out all combinations in a list but cannot be duplicated

Tags: python, list, combinators

I have a list: `['1','2','3','4']`

I would like to find out all combination within the list but not allow duplicated values (`"1|2"=="2|1"`)

Output:

```
1|1
1|2
1|3
1|4
2|2
2|3
2|4
3|3
3|4
4|4
```

```
list=['1','2','3','4']
list2= list
for img1 in list:
    for img2 in list2:
        print(img1,"|",img2)
    list2.remove(img1)
```

Comment: pls use `list2 = ['1', '2', '3', '4']` or `list2 = list.copy()`. This is why https://stackoverflow.com/a/2612815/16182150

Comment: Cool!! it works. but i would like to ask what is the difference between them.